# Brackets Text Editor - "Go to anything" feature like Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, brackets

I love Sublime Text and I'm playing with Brackets editor for a change. One of the features I like most in ST is the "Go to anything" (CTRL+P).

Is there something like that in Brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets v1.6 + [Brackets Commands Quick Search](https://github.com/peterflynn/brackets-commands-guide) is the closest to SublimeText's "Go to anything".

Install extension and then <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + O</kbd> (Menu -> Navigate -> **Quick Open**). Only difference is that Bracket doesn't show unsaved files (tabs).

Note: "Go to anything" in Sublime Text meaning = go to any file in project / opened tabs (ie. unsaved files / drafts)